# How to select field from a row using MAX on another column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use an outer join from table A to a row on table B (which may not exist). I need to join on a date field in table B, which should be taken from the row which has the highest sequence number.

e.g.

Table B:

```
ID | A_DATE     | SEQNO
1    01/01/1950   10
1    01/01/2000   5
```

So here I would need to join A and B for ID 1 using `A.id = 1 and A.a_date = 01/01/1950` (the highest sequence number for ID 1).

I don't think this syntax is correct:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a, b
WHERE a.id (+) = b.id
  AND ...
```

I'm lost - can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know your database schema, but joining on a date (non-unique row) sounds quite evil.
Instead I would recommend you to google 'JOIN' and learn it yourself. It's not a topic one learns in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `a_date` associated with the maximum value of `seq_no` by using the `keep` keyword:

```
select ...
from a join
     (select max(A_DATE) keep (dense_rank first order by seq_no desc) as max_a_date
      from b
     ) bmax
     on a.a_date = b.max_a_date;
```

The rest of the query just joins to this date.  This query does not need an outer join, at least as I understand the problem.

Note:  this assumes that table b exists.  You cannot write a regular SQL query that works regardless of whether or not a table exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I have correctly understood.

Try this:

```
select ...
from (select id,
              max(A_DATE) over(partition by id) as a_date
      from a) a,
     b
where a.id     = b.id (+)
  and a.a_date = b.b_date (+);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should be `last_value` rather than `max`. I think `max` will select the greatest `A_DATE` (which won't be affected by the `order by SEQNO` at all) rather than the `A_DATE` with the greatest corresponding `SEQNO`. (Also, I'm pretty sure that the OP actually needs the subquery to be over B rather than over A, but the question is confusing.)

Comment: Yes, ORDER BY is not correct (I removed it). But my query gets the most recent Date, without considering the SEQNO. You are right, we must consider the date with the greatest SEQNO. If so, Gordon has given a good answer... :)